# Extracting Integer value from Object Java

Tags: java, object

I have this following piece of code to find the maximum frequency number in an array

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){
    Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i:arr)
        m.put(i,m.getOrDefault(i,0)+1);
    int num,max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(Map.Entry e:m.entrySet()){
        if(e.getValue().intValue()>max){
            num=e.getKey().intValue();
            max=e.getValue().intValue();
        }
    }
    return max;

}
```

}

Now the issue with this is `Map.Entry e.getValue()` returns Object type and `.intValue` doesn't work on Object (only Integer objects I guess) so is there a way to extract the integer value stored in a variable of type Object?

Comment: A raw type like `Map.Entry` should never be used. If the correct type arguments are given, then the abovementioned problem disapprears as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use generic types for `Entry`:

```
  for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e:m.entrySet()){
    if(e.getValue().intValue()>max){
        num=e.getKey().intValue();
        max=e.getValue().intValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with the problem. Also, you can simplify your code by using `Math.max`.

**1. Replace the raw type with the parameterized type (the recommended way):**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(maxFrequencyNumber(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 10, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10 }));
    }

    public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i : arr) {
            m.put(i, m.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
        }
        int num, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
            max = Math.max(max, e.getValue());
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**2. Cast `e.getValue()` to `(Integer)`:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(maxFrequencyNumber(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 10, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10 }));
    }

    public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i : arr) {
            m.put(i, m.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
        }
        int num, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Map.Entry e : m.entrySet()) {
            max = Math.max(max, (Integer) e.getValue());
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

**Additional note:** Since you do not need keys in the map, you could simply iterate `Map::values` as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(maxFrequencyNumber(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 10, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10 }));
    }

    public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i : arr) {
            m.put(i, m.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
        }
        int num, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Integer i : m.values()) {
            max = Math.max(max, i);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `Map<Integer, Integer>` map so you can iterate over its keys erasing your `Map.Entry` problem like below:

```
int num, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (Integer key : m.keySet()) {
    int value = m.get(key);
    if (value > max) {
        num = key;
        max = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more efficient to iterate over the entry set, if you need keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes with casting

```
  public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){
      Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
      for(int i:arr)
          m.put(i,m.getOrDefault(i,0)+1);
      int num,max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for(Map.Entry e:m.entrySet()){
          if(((Integer)e.getValue()).intValue()>max){
              num=((Integer)e.getKey()).intValue();
              max=((Integer)e.getValue()).intValue();
          }
      }
      return max; 
  }
```

Comment: Generics are the recommended way